# Existence of $2$ permutations of $S_n$ such that $\pi_1 \circ{} \pi_1 ^{-1}= \pi_2\circ{}\pi_2^{-1}=\pi_1 \circ{} \pi_2^{-1}=[n n-1 ... 1]$

Tags: permutations, function-and-relation-composition

I have been thinking about this problem for a while but I can't think of any solution. I can think of a solution for $\pi_1  \circ{} \pi_1^{-1} = \pi_2\circ{}\pi_2^{-1}=\pi_1 \circ{} \pi_2^{-1}=Id$ such as any $\pi_1=\pi_2=$ an involution (for example: $\pi_1=(12)$ then $\pi_1\circ{}\pi_1^{-1}=Id$). However, I can't think of any satisfying the opposite of the Identity. Any help?

Comment: "$=Id$" means that $\pi _2 = \pi _1$

Comment: @Phicar Yes, but the problem I am struggling with is not the Identity, its $[n-1...1]$ or the opposite of the identity.

Comment: Ah 0k, so please edit to see it in the question. Another thing: In your notation $[n,n-1,\cdots ,1]$ is the cycle or the word notation? I.e $[n,n-1,\cdots ,1](n)=n-1$ or $[n,n-1,\cdots ,1](n)=1$?

Comment: @Phicar Thanks for commenting on my notation, I figured out I was lost because the notation I used was incorrect. I've found a solution and posted it as an answer! Thanks!

Comment: Wait, My solution is incorrect :/. It doesn't satisfy $\pi_1\circ{}\pi_1^{-1}=\pi_2\circ{}\pi_2^{-1}=[nn-1...1]$. Only the last condition is satisfied :/

Comment: Is impossible to satisfy that. $S_n$ is a group hence has to be identity.

Comment: @Phicar Ahh, I see. Thank you for your answer. I understand now!

Answer (score 1):

I just realized I missed the solution because of my incorrect notation. Let me explain.
$[nn-1...1]$ is a permutation that can be represented as
$$(1\text{ }n)\circ{}(2\text{ }n-1)\circ{}...\circ{}(\frac{n}{2}\text{ }\frac{n-2}{2}) \text{ if n is even}$$
$$(1\text{ }n)\circ{}(2\text{ }n-1)\circ{}...\circ{}(\frac{n-1}{2}\text{ }\frac{n-3}{2}) \text{ if n is odd}$$
For example, take $n=6$. Then the reverse permutation is $(16)\circ{(25)}\circ{}(34)$. Now I am looking for two permutations $\pi_1\circ{\pi_2^{-1}}=(16)\circ{(25)}\circ{}(34)$ or $\pi_1=(16)\circ{(25)}\circ{}(34)\circ{}\pi_2$.

So I will let $\pi_2$ be any involution, say $\pi_2=(34)$. Then $\pi_1=(16)\circ{(25)}\circ{}(34)\circ{}(34)=(16)\circ{(25)}$ which is also a involution. So $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ satisfy all three conditions.

**Edit: My solution is incorrect. It doesn't satisfy $\pi_1\circ{}\pi_1^{-1}=\pi_2\circ{}\pi_2^{-1}=[nn-1...1]$**